# Where is my JavaDoc in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, javadoc

Where do I have to configure where Jenkins can find JavaDoc files. I did see that the JavaDoc-Plugin is installed but I did not find any place where I would be able to configure it.

This is my pom.xml

```
<build>
   <plugins>
      ...
     <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

<reporting>
        <plugins>
             <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

thx a lot

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**For Freestyle jobs**
If you have installed the Javadoc plugin (and have since restarted Jenkins, if you're using Jenkins 1.441 or older), you should see an option in the job configuration.

Under "Post-build Actions" check the "Publish Javadoc" item and then enter the path to your generated Javadoc, relative to the workspace.

**For Maven jobs**
If you generate Javadoc from your Maven build, and you use the Maven job type in Jenkins, it should be automatically published on the web page for each module built in Jenkins.

See also: http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/Show-Javadoc-in-Maven2-project-td2340256.html

Comment: I have these options(restarted jenkins again):                     
  

Aggregate downstream test results/Archive the artifacts/Build other projects/Deploy artifacts to Artifactory/Deploy artifacts to Maven repository/Publish Clover Coverage Repor/Publish Cobertura Coverage Report

Comment: Does the Jenkins Javadoc plugin appear in the plugin manager under "Installed", or is it still in "Available"?

Comment: Ah, you're using the Maven job type, which handles things differently it seems. I updated the answer.